# C# Code Analysis dislikes protected static s_Foo (CA1709, CA1707)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, naming-conventions, code-analysis, fxcop

I usually add an `m_` in front of `private` fields and an `s_` before `static` members.

With a code like

```
protected static readonly Random s_Random = new Random ();
```

I get the following warnings by VS2008's Code Analysis:

- `CA1709`: Microsoft.Naming : Correct the casing of 's' in member name 'Bar.s_Random' by changing it to 'S'.
- `CA1707`: Microsoft.Naming : Remove the underscores from member name 'Bar.s_Random'.

How to resolve this issue? Should I simply remove the `s_`? Or add a global suppression for this warning?

**Edit:** My company lacks coding standards, so it's up to me to define them for my code. (Yea I know...)

If you think `s_` should be removed in general, I'd be glad if you could provide official sources.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not following Microsoft's .NET naming convention that tells you not to prefix stuff with anything. If this is really what you want, add a suppression. Otherwise, follow the guideline by getting rid of `s_` and other similar prefixes.

From [Names of Type Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx):
"Names of Fields" Section: "Do not use a prefix for field names. For example, do not use g_ or s_ to distinguish static versus non-static fields."

Answer (score 1):

1. Unload the project
2. Right click on the unloaded project => Edit csproj
3. Make RunCodeAnalysis to false
4. Save and reload project

Comment: i maybe did not understood the question very well, but i wrote that answer because i did it and that solution helped me.
There was a VS update that made my project not able to build, and the company used a specefic naming convention that i couldnt change. So the solution was useful

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want.

If your company policy is to prefix static members with s_ then you should suppress the warning and even add your own rule.

Otherwise fix it to Microsoft's standards and call your member `Random`.

Comment: (`Random` is already the name of the class)

Answer (score 0):

m_ is an old standard for naming.  Newer conventions are to not follow this Hungarian notation.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no clear consensus on this topic. Could you provide some sources of a deprecation of m_?

Comment: @Will - which is hilarious. "Do as we say, not as we do" - MS

Comment: That's not hungarian notation, [since it does not indicate the variable's type or use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164506.aspx), but it being a class member. There are good reasons for the m_ prefix and many people recommend it (eg. [Steve McConnell](http://cc2e.com/Page.aspx?hid=225) - "Does the convention distinguish among local, class, and global data?").

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you how you want to resolve it. Ignore it, and keep your own naming convention, or follow up the Microsoft standard. Personally, I do not use any prefix for my variables (so that would be 'random' instead of 's_Random' in this case) so I would go with the latter, but if you're really comfortable with this, then nobody forces you to change.

Answer (score 0):

- CA1709 : protected  is not private and needs to be upper case
- CA1707 : underscores are not according to ms naming convention